# Why are some systemd services in the "masked" state?

Tags: systemd

When I run the command `sudo systemctl list-unit-files` (I think the sudo is optional), I get output which shows all services and their state.

Here is a snippet from my machine:

```
UNIT FILE                                  STATE
...
debian-fixup.service                       static  
debug-shell.service                        disabled
display-manager.service                    enabled 
dns-clean.service                          enabled 
dsmcad.service                             enabled 
emergency.service                          static  
failsafe-x.service                         static  
friendly-recovery.service                  masked  
fuse.service                               masked  
gdm.service                                masked  
getty-static.service                       static  
getty@.service                             enabled 
gpsd.service                               indirect
gpsdctl@.service                           static  
gpu-manager.service                        enabled 
halt-local.service                         static  
halt.service                               masked  
hostname.service                           masked
...
```

I wonder why some services are in the "masked" state. I think this means, "this is better than 'disabling', because the service cannot be started, neither by hand or by systemd".

How can I get more information about the state of a service unit?

Who has put the units into their respective state?

I tried, for example, 
`sudo systemctl help dsmcad` - that only brings up the `documentation = ...` line from the unit file. `/etc/systemd/system/dsmcad.service`

Note: Here I know *exactly* what dsmcad service is and what it does, I have installed it myself. I am more interested in a general solution.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

`mask` is a stronger version of `disable`. Using `disable` all symlinks of the specified unit file are removed. If using `mask` the units will be linked to `/dev/null`. This will be displayed if you check e.g. by `systemctl status halt.service`. The advantage of `mask` is to prevent any kind of activation, even manual.

Caution: `systemctl list-unit-files` is listing the state of the unit **files** (static, enabled, disabled, masked, indirect) and has nothing to do with the state of the service. To have a look at the **services** use `systemctl list-units`.

Comment: Please also explain how to remove the masked state, if desired.

Comment: There is a `mask` and an `unmask` command that can be used with `systemctl`.  So just do `systemctl unmask name_of_service.service`.

Comment: doing `systemctl unmask name_of_service.service` completely removed my service definition file from `/etc/systemd/system/`, so now I need to add it back again. If it becomes masked again, I'll be stuck in a loop o.O

Comment: Hi Eldamir, in `/etc/systemd/system` are just symbolic links of services. Your should add the `*.service` file to `/lib/systemd/system` from where it will be linked to `/etc/systemd/system` if you `enable` the service. `mask` is creating a link to `/dev/null` and `unmask` is removing this link from `/etc/systemd/system` and obviously it makes no difference if someone put a file there.

Answer (score 7):

'mask' is a state of unit files which is considered as the "third level of off" (stop-1st, disable-2nd, mask-3rd). The services labeled as masked can neither be started manually (using the start command) nor by systems (at system boot). Therefore, use caution when employing the systemctl mask command on a service.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are requesting information about the masked state, it is important to mention that it can be observed in a service that after started, had it definitions modified, reload (systemctl daemon-reload) and the **new state is NOT ok**.
One easy example to understand it is the following scenario:

```
a) the service is running well (already started)
b) edit the service definition file and delete everything in its contents
c) reload
d) state masked will be observed too
```

Hence, the masked state may be originated from a improper service definitions.
Therefore, the user may induce unmasked state by editing improperly the service.

*Observation: I'm not sure if it happens on purpose or it is a simple bug (default option), but it may be some interesting info to share*

Answer (score 3):

`hostname.service` is masked as redundant because `systemd` sets the hostname (from /etc/hostname) very early on during startup.

This setting is provided by the Debian systemd package.

```
$ ls -l /lib/systemd/system/hostname.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Apr  8 22:47 /lib/systemd/system/hostname.service -> /dev/null
$ dpkg-query --search /lib/systemd/system/hostname.service
systemd: /lib/systemd/system/hostname.service
```

Similarly, Debian can now run without a shell script to `halt` the system, it's handled by [systemd-shutdown](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-update-2.html) (source code [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/core/shutdown.c)) instead.

If a service has been masked manually, the mask will be installed in `/etc/systemd/system` instead.

[Services are also masked when they are removed on Debian/Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369713/removing-debian-package-automatically-masks-systemd-service-causes-a-systemd-w).  I don't know why.

Comment: Masking vs. removing of services comes with the difference of removing vs. purging a package. In the first case the config-files are kept and thus it might be potentially dangerous to activate a service by mistake (as the service file might still be in the config files). A purged package will also have the service files removed and not masked.