# error: Unit mongodb.service is masked when starting mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to install kaa(IOT platform) on installing the dependencies getting an error on executing the command-

```
$ sudo systemctl start mongodb
error- Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service is masked.
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> Unit mongodb.service is masked.

So unmask it:

```
sudo systemctl unmask mongodb
```

[Why are some systemd services in the "masked" state?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710420/why-are-some-systemd-services-in-the-masked-state)  explains masking.

Comment: I also received this error after installing mongodb-org. Why was it masked by default? What does that mean to be masked?

Comment: sorry. no it does not, is UNMASKS the service file. where do you see an "rm" in this command? Please read up on what masks/unmasks means And the topic starter agrees with me ;-)

Comment: Just another stupid systemd "feature".  Systemd is full of charming "surprises".  Like [PrivateTmp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448056/systemd-private-tmp-on-debian-cant-disable-it-on-the-right-way), which silently writes things you intend to go into `/tmp` into some "magic" directory in Never-Never Land...

Answer (score 9):

With 3+ version of mongodb. You dont have to start `mongodb` but you just have to start mongod. So proper way to start mongod will be

`sudo systemctl start mongod`

Comment: `Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found`.  Change `mongod `to `mongodb` and hte result is `Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service is masked.`

Comment: Yup.  By default, you still have to "unmask" it: `sudo systemctl unmask mongodb`.  Silly, silly, silly.  But at least it's documented.  Sort of...