# How to upgrade MongoDB from 2.6 to 3.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mongodb

I have Ubuntu 16.04 machine with MongoDB 2.6.10 install.

Now I want to upgrade MongoDB to latest version, i.e., 3.4

What is the best way to Upgrade?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: sudo apt install mongodb-clients , sudo apt install mongodb-server , sudo apt install mongodb

Comment: Above post gives PUBKEY_ERR<br>
Refer this :[Apt-get fails on 16.04 or 18.04 installing mongodb](https://askubuntu.com/a/842599)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do as following

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6

$ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list

$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

after upgrading your service will be masked. To unmask it

```
sudo systemctl unmask mongodb
```

for more detail see:

- How to Upgrade MongoDB to Latest Stable Version – Mongoaudit — the mongoaudit guides – Medium -> https://medium.com/mongoaudit/how-to-upgrade-mongodb-to-latest-stable-version-9607266834cf
- error: Unit mongodb.service is masked when starting mongodb - Ask Ubuntu -> [error: Unit mongodb.service is masked when starting mongodb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919108/error-unit-mongodb-service-is-masked-when-starting-mongodb)

### update:

If you use different ubuntu version, you should update `<UBUNTU VERSION>` in this command:

```
$ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu <UBUNTU VERSION>/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
```

For example, if you use 18.10, change it to `cosmic`
You can find your version with this command

```
$ lsb_release -a
```

Comment: show error :
W: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: @MahdiBagheri use proxy, this is blocked in iran

Comment: This would only work for "Ubuntu Xenial", see this article for more info: https://medium.com/mongoaudit/how-to-upgrade-mongodb-to-latest-stable-version-9607266834cf